# Prevent SMS Verification Abuse

Tags: python, sms

my app requires phone number verification (using Twilio or Similar) but I need some sort of abuse prevention method.

Do you guys have any recommendations besides standard CAPTCHA?

I cannot block IPs after X attemps because half my users might be sharing the same IP.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: maybe get them to verify an email address first?

Comment: no, that is adding an extra step and wont work

Comment: See below link: - [How To Stop A Mobile Verification Attack](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/130779/how-to-stop-a-mobile-verification-attack)
- [Prevent against OTP abuse in app sign up flow](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184619/prevent-against-otp-abuse-in-app-sign-up-flow)